# Multi Threading: Two Threads vs Nested Threads Python

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I want to speed up my program as much as possible. Can someone help me which will be better in terms of speed? As per my requirement I can go with any approach.

Approach 1 (spawned 2 threads from main process):

```
def a(something):
    # Does something at fixed interval
    while 1:
        print("a")
        time.sleep(60)


def b(something):
    # Keeps running for infinitely without any delay.
    while 1:
        print("b")


def main():

    something = {}

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=b, args=(something,))
    t1.start()

    t2 = threading.Thread(target=a, args=(something,))
    t2.start()
```

Approach 2 (spawned a nested thread):

```
def a(something):
    # Does something at fixed interval
    while 1:
        print("a")
        time.sleep(60)


def b(something):
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=a, args=(something,))
    t2.start()
    # Keeps running for infinitely without any delay.
    while 1:
        print("b")


def main():

    something = {}

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=b, args=(something,))
    t1.start()
```

P.S. *a* and *b* are just dummy functions but does the things in similar way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The coexistence of threads is flat, not hierarchical**. A thread does not operate within another thread. (I am pretty sure that this is the case for CPython, it would be nice if someone can check it).

In other words, there is no difference between a thread spawned within the *main thread* and a thread spawned within any other thread (what you refer to a *nested thread*).

Regarding the other small differences between your two approaches (such as global vs local variables), they would hardly affect speed.

And finally, in *this* particular case multithreading would work as expected, the Python's infamous GIL Lock won't have any effects (the `time.sleep()` block would be avoided by rescheduling threads).

Comment: Alright, so no major difference. Regarding the last part you mentioned, rescheduling thread vs sleeping thread, which is better?

Comment: The rescheduling of a sleeping thread happens automatically. I was just saying that for that specific case, whenever the `time.sleep()` is blocking one of the thread, the other will be running. In other words, Python's multithreading will have a speed up effect and you "don't need" multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple threats i suggest you look into multiprocessing, while heavier python's threads effectively will only run in one CPU core no matter how many of them you use. This is due to the GIL lock and that's why multiprocessing is used to get around that.

An alternative would be to use PyPy which is a different python implementation than the official with speedups is some cases and without GIL, which can allow for mutlithreading efficienlty

Comment: I need to share memory across threads and sharing memory in multiprocessing is not direct and perhaps decrease the speed. Let me check for PyPy which you suggested.